# Creating / Re-creating the X,Y,Z mesh Surface functions with the (u,v) options using python

Tags: python, animation, mesh, mathematics, bmesh

Creating / Re-creating the X,Y,Z mesh Surface function with the (u,v) options using python in **Blender 2.8x**

Does an example exist / anyone have an example of how to reproduce the X,Y,Z mesh Surface functions / ad-don with (u,v) options.  **Just using python and Blender 2.8x**?

I'm trying to do some animation with it using python but I can't find a way to get just those particular functions I would need.

This is the functions i'm talking about.
[image]

I'm referring to the arrows and highlighted sections below when referring to **(u,v)** options  (**They are connected mathematically**)

[image: UV image]

Comment: Hello, could you describe what are the (u,v) options you are talking about ?

Comment: @Gorgious I added an image showing this.